# django. Passing id from one template to second template

Tags: python, django

I need to pass id from one template to another template. In template i am iterating over one model

```
{% for project in all_projects %}

<h3>{{ project.name }}</h3>
<a href="{% url 'docs:platforms' %}?project={{ project.id }}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

This going to one template where my url looks like

```
    url(r'^$', views.ProjectsListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^platforms/$', views.PlatformsIndexView.as_view(), name='platforms'),
    url(r'^platforms/nodes/$', views.PlatformsNodesListView.as_view(), name='platforms_list'),
```

Browser url  that i have is **http://127.0.0.1:8000/platforms/?project=1**
that's ok good. But from second template i need to send third template another parametrs and filters. So how do i can get id of project?

I can not send now project id to third template because i am not iterating over it. How to remember id of project?

**views.py**

```
class ProjectsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'project/projects.html'
    model = Project
    context_object_name = 'all_projects'


class PlatformsIndexView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'project/platforms.html'


class PlatformsNodesListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'project/general.html'
    model = Platform
    context_object_name = 'all_platforms'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        type_filter = self.request.GET.get('type')
        project_filter = self.request.GET.get('project')

        if type_filter in [Platform.BACKEND, Platform.ANDROID, Platform.IOS, Platform.FRONTEND]:
            queryset = queryset.filter(type=type_filter)
        if project_filter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(project__id__exact=project_filter)
        else:
            raise Http404
        return queryset
```

Please explain me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Post your view and template where you are facing problems

Comment: You can get `{{ request.GET.project }}` in template. Hope this helps

Comment: i can not get id because i am not iterating over the project model.

Comment: Please post your code where you need id. Also models which shows relation platform-project

Comment: Oh thank you. I found solution